# Call Svelte component's function from global scope

Tags: javascript, google-signin, svelte, sapper

I am creating a Sapper page, where I'd like to use [Google Sign-in button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in). It requires `data-onsuccess` attribute to specify callback function. From what I was able to discover from Google's platform JS library, it looks for the function in the global/`window` scope.

Is there a way to access/call Svelte's component function from global webpage scope? It might be of use for interop with external libraries which cannot be loaded through `import` right into the component.

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
<script>
  function onSignComponent(user){
    console.log('Signed in');
  }
</script>

<div id="login" class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="{onSignComponent}" data-theme="dark" />
```

This work when `onSignComponent` is in global scope but not when it is in component scope.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is just to put the function on `window` inside the component:

```js
<script>
  window.onSignIn = user => {
    // ...
  };
</script>

<div id="login" class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark" />
```

Comment: Wow, that is embarrassingly simple. I should have thought about that while trying another workaround (attaching svelte stores to window object). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

One way to do this would be to add `<svelte:window on:xxx>` directive in your component and then in the method `onSignComponent` raise this *xxx* event.

**in component**

```
<svelte:window on:loginSuccess={loginSuccess}></svelte:window>
```

**somewhere else**

```
const myEvent = new CustomEvent('loginSuccess', { ... some object });
window.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

Comment: Cool. I thought about `svelte:window` but didn't know I could connect it with custom events