# [GSI_LOGGER]: The value of 'callback' is not a function. Configuration ignored

Tags: svelte, google-identity

I'm [migrating](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration) from [Google Sign-in platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) to the newer [Google Identity Services library](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web).

App.svelte:

```js
<svelte:head>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
</svelte:head>

<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="x.apps.googleusercontent.com"
     data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">
</div>
<div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-size="large"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="sign_in_with"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
```

```js
<script>
    function decodeJwtResponse(token) {
        let base64Url = token.split('.')[1]
        let base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
        let jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {
            return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join(''));
        return JSON.parse(jsonPayload)
    }

    let responsePayload;
    function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        // decodeJwtResponse() is a custom function defined by you
        // to decode the credential response.
        responsePayload = decodeJwtResponse(response.credential);

        console.log("ID: " + responsePayload.sub);
        console.log('Full Name: ' + responsePayload.name);
        console.log('Given Name: ' + responsePayload.given_name);
        console.log('Family Name: ' + responsePayload.family_name);
        console.log("Image URL: " + responsePayload.picture);
        console.log("Email: " + responsePayload.email);
    }
</script>
```

Reloading the page and I saw this error in the console:

> [GSI_LOGGER]: The value of 'callback' is not a function. Configuration ignored.

What is the problem?

Comment: Hi, I don't know about svelte, but can't you move the app-loading script tag (`<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>`) out of the svelte tag? If I modify your code that way, I can run this successfully.

Answer (score 14):

After many hours searching, I found this answer: [Call Svelte component's function from global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57954008/call-svelte-components-function-from-global-scope)

Simply, `handleCredentialResponse` needs to be global (window) scope.

**JavaScript**

```js
window.handleCredentialResponse = (response) => {
  // decodeJwtResponse() is a custom function defined by you
  // to decode the credential response.
  responsePayload = decodeJwtResponse(response.credential);

  console.log("ID: " + responsePayload.sub);
  console.log('Full Name: ' + responsePayload.name);
  console.log('Given Name: ' + responsePayload.given_name);
  console.log('Family Name: ' + responsePayload.family_name);
  console.log("Image URL: " + responsePayload.picture);
  console.log("Email: " + responsePayload.email);
}
```

**TypeScript**

You need to modify `Window` interface so that TS won't raise error: [How do you explicitly set a new property on `window` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

```js
// global.d.ts

export {};

declare global {
  interface Window {
    handleCredentialResponse: (response: any) => void;
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing Answer...! This works well to get the user information from the new GSI implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like we have to render the Sign In With Google button by using [Javascript](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button#javascript).

- https://www.nielsvandermolen.com/external-javascript-sveltejs/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/otbrsm/how_do_i_add_a_script_normally_used_with_script/h6wvopt

```js
<svelte:head>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer on:load={googleLoaded}></script>
</svelte:head>

<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let googleReady = false;
    let mounted = false;

    onMount(() => {
        mounted = true;
        if (googleReady) {
            displaySignInButton()
        }
    });

    function googleLoaded() {
        googleReady = true;
        if (mounted) {
            displaySignInButton()
        }
    }

    function displaySignInButton() {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: "x.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            callback: handleCredentialResponse
        });
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
            { theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
        );
        google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
    }
```

Comment: 10 points for using on:load and preventing a race condition

Comment: ...although it doesn't seem to work on client side navigation. Might be better off adding the script tag via js in that scenario

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, `handleCredentialResponse` needs to be global.

Using `window.handleCredentialResponse` won't cut it in svelte.

Using `globalThis.handleCredentialResponse` however will work.

So **instead of** `const handleCredentialResponse = async (response) => {}`

**DO THIS**: `globalThis.handleCredentialResponse = async (response) => {}`

Answer (score 1):

Like others mentioned, the issue here is that the callback function needs to be globally accessible. Hence why we need to attach it to window.

However, if you're using [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) with **SSR**, the window object doesn't exist until the client side renders and you'll get an internal server error. The solution to this is to attach the function *after* the component has mounted. However again, I was still getting your error. It seems that the google script was running before my onMount statement.

So, I had to do the following, basically initializing the two buttons using Google's scripts *after* mount.

```
<script>
    import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    onMount(() => {
        // Define the handleSignInWithGoogle function
        // @ts-ignore
        window.handleSignInWithGoogle = async function (response) {     
        };

        // Load the Google Sign-In library
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client';
        script.async = true;
        script.onload = function () {
            // Initialize the Google Sign-In library
            // @ts-ignore
            window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
                client_id: 'blablabla.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                // @ts-ignore
                callback: window.handleSignInWithGoogle,
                context: 'signin',
                ux_mode: 'popup',
                nonce: '',
                auto_select: true,
                itp_support: true
            });
            // @ts-ignore
            window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById('g_id_onload'), {
                type: 'standard',
                shape: 'pill',
                theme: 'outline',
                text: 'signin_with',
                size: 'large',
                logo_alignment: 'left'
            });
        };
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
</script>

<div id="g_id_onload" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by: globalThis.handleToken

Comment: Hi @minor How would you write handleCredentialResponse or handleToken in typescript and NOT in java script? I am getting error in console '[GSI_LOGGER]: The value of 'callback' is not a function. Configuration ignored.'

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a short way if they are trying to implement login with google in angular.

I've used event broadcast and listen method to make it simpler.

from the google callback function

```
function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
      const lgwtggl = new CustomEvent("lgwtggl", {
        detail: response
      });
      document.dispatchEvent(lgwtggl);
    }
```

and from inside any angular component listen like below

```
// listen on event google login response
    document.addEventListener('lgwtggl', (e: any) => {
      if (e && e.detail && e.type === 'lgwtggl') {
    // call component function
        this.loginWithGoogle(e.detail);
      }
    });
```

and the controller function goes like below

```
public loginWithGoogle(payload: any) {
// your logic
    console.log(payload);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working version for Angular 15 either call it in `ngOnInit` or inside `constructor`. Here is the typescript version

```
 ngOnInit() {
       //For button login
       (globalThis as any).handleCredentialResponse = (response: any) => {
        // Handle the response here
        console.log('Received credential response:', response);
        //api call or jwt decode or any other logics will go here

      };
  }
```